# Avoid masterpage post back

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if there is a way to load Content Page without loading the Master page (ASP WebForms for .NET 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

No, a MasterPage **is a part of** any `ContentPage` using it.

### At run time, master pages are handled in the following sequence:

- Users request a page by typing the URL of the content page
- When the page is fetched, the @ Page directive is read. If the directive references a master page, the master page is read as well. If this is the first time the pages have been requested, both pages are compiled.
- The master page with the updated content is merged into the control tree of the content page.
- The content of individual Content controls **is merged into the corresponding ContentPlaceHolder control in the master page**.
- The resulting merged page is rendered to the browser.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

You should explain what you're actually trying to achieve(or to prevent), because a postback is a postback - with or without a MasterPage.

Comment: i want to load content pages without reloading of master pages or post back of master pages how to do that

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that? Are you using ASP.NET-Ajax and you want to prevent part of the page from being updated? Then use UpdatePanels as @Joe has suggested. Otherwise you must provide source code so that we can suggest another approach(maybe you've put something into the MasterPage's Page_Load that does not belong there).

Comment: i have menus on master page and i want  when i click of anyone menu then master page dont postback and only content page i got how to do that?????

Comment: @user1266026: Don't mix [MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) with frames. They are an absolutely different concept.

Comment: Again, why do you need to prevent the MasterPage from "loading"? What are you doing there? I assume that you've missed somewhere a simple [`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) check.

Comment: i have menus on master pages like that systemAdmin setup when i click on systemAdmin the systemAdmin page open as content page and also master page load i want when i click on systemAdmin or setup link only content page open master page header and menus remain same

Comment: @user1266026: You should edit your question to show what you're doing in the MasterPage(also the relevant part in codebehind). Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)?

E.g. with something like the following in your Master Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MasterUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MasterPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            Child page content goes here
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i want to load content pages without reloading of master pages or post back of master pages how to do that –

Comment: i have menus on master page and i want  when i click of anyone menu then master page dont postback and only content page i got how to do that?????

Comment: i have menus on master pages like that systemAdmin setup when i click on systemAdmin the systemAdmin page open as content page and also master page load i want when i click on systemAdmin or setup link only content page open master page header and menus remain same